# How would I write a bash function that can extract all common archive files?

Tags: bash

I'd like to have a bash function that can extract zip, tar, tar.gz and other archives.

How can this be done?

Comment: You can write a function using a text editor and put it in your startup files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a function I have found a long time ago somewhere in the internet:

```
extract () {
    if [ -f "$1" ] ; then
        case $1 in
            *.tar.bz2)   tar xvjf "$1" ;;
            *.tar.gz)    tar xvzf "$1" ;;
            *.tar.xz)    tar xvJf "$1" ;;
            *.bz2)       bunzip2 "$1" ;;
            *.rar)       unrar x "$1" ;;
            *.gz)        gunzip "$1" ;;
            *.tar)       tar xvf "$1" ;;
            *.tbz2)      tar xvjf "$1" ;;
            *.tgz)       tar xvzf "$1" ;;
            *.zip)       unzip "$1" ;;
            *.jar)       unzip "$1" ;;
            *.Z)         uncompress "$1" ;;
            *.7z)        7z x "$1" ;;
            *)           echo "'$1' cannot be extracted via >extract<" ;;
        esac
    else
        echo "'$1' is not a valid file"
    fi
}
```

(I am not sure who is the author, so I am making this answer a community wiki)

Answer (score 0):

Try `atool` http://www.nongnu.org/atool/ -- atool is a script for managing file archives of various types (tar, tar+gzip, zip etc).